# Vertex AI AutoML Batch Predict returns prediction scores as Array Float64 in BigQuery Table instead of just FLOAT64 values>

Tags: google-bigquery, artificial-intelligence, tabular, vertex, automl

So I have this tabular AutoML model in Vertex AI. It successfully ran batch predictions and outputs to BigQuery. However, when I try to query the prediction data based off of the score being above a certain threshold, I get an error saying the datatype doesn't support float operations. When I tried to cast the scores to float, it said that the scores are a float64 array? This confuses me because they're just individual values of a column in the table. I don't understand why they aren't normal floats, nor do I know how to convert them. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I tried casting the datatype to float, which obviously didn't work. I tried using different operators like BETWEEN and LIKE, but again won't work because it says it's an array. I just don't understand why it's getting converted to an array. Each value should be its own value just as the table shows it to be.

Answer (score 0):

AutoML does store your result in a so called RECORD, at least if you're doing classification. If that is the case for you, it stores two things within this RECORD: classes and scores. Scores itself is also an array, consisting of the probability of 0 and the probability of 1. So to access it you have to do something like this:

```
prediction_variable.scores[offset(1)]
```

This will give you the value for the probability of your classification being 1.